# Working of function pointers

Tags: c++

In this Program, I am unable to understand the declaration of the "sum" function.

Please explain what is happening while calling the sum function and while declaring the function.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

int sum(int(*)(int),int);
int square(int);
int cube(int);

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    cout<<sum(square,4)<<endl;
    cout<<sum(cube,4)<<endl;
    getch();
}

int sum(int(*ptr)(int k),int n)
{
     int s=0;
     for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
         s+=(*ptr)(i);
     }
     return s;
}

int square(int k)
{
int sq;
sq=k*k;
return k*k;
}

int cube(int k) 
{
    return k*k*k;
}
```

Comment: Aside: please move the 3 function prototypes out of main, to below the `#include`s.

Comment: Why declaring a function prototype inside a function body?

Comment: Mandatory critical comment on use of conio.h, iostream.h and void main. To OP, wherever you are learning this stuff from, learn it from somewhere else.

Comment: The whole thing is a mish-mash. Why use `conio.h`? Why the `void main()`? Why the different ways of implementing `square` and `cube`? Why compute `sq=k*k;` and then `return k*k;` ignoring `sq`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reason why some people does not like pointers in C and C++. See my explanation below in your program:-

```
#include<iostream.h>
# include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int sum(int(*)(int),int);// Here first parameter in `sum` is a pointer to a function which return type is int.  `int(*)(int)` here int(*) is function pointer and (int) is its parameter type. 
    int square(int);
    int cube(int);
    cout<<sum(square,4)<<endl;// Now you are passing address of function  `square` as first parameter and its parameter 4, like square(4)
    cout<<sum(cube,4)<<endl; // Here you are passing address of function `cube` as parameter and 4 as parameter to cube function
    getch();
}

int sum(int(*ptr)(int k),int n)
{
     int s=0;
     for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
         s+=(*ptr)(i); //This `ptr` is nothing but the address of function passed to sum
    //hence it execute like below
    //When you are calling function `sum` with function pointer `square` as first parameter  
        //it execute like `s = s + square(i);`
        //Now at the second call to `sum` it execute like `s = s + cube(i);`
     }
     return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is a function pointer - you should read [here](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) for an introduction, and [heres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) a relevant SO post.

The idea is that you can pass around a function as a value - so you can make other general functions that you can give a specific function to in order to change the effect. An example would be `map` from functional programming.

Specifically in your case, the `sum` function takes this function pointer in order to sum a function of the values in the list given to it, rather than just the values themselves. This is demonstrated by passing it eg. a pointer to the `square` function, which will make it sum squares of the values given to `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// The method sum 
// First argument: a pointer to a function which accepts one integer 
// as argument and returns an integer
// Second argument: an integer
int sum(int(*)(int),int);
```

That is why when you call `sum` in this line:

```
cout<<sum(square,4)<<endl;
```

You pass `square` as the first argument and since `square` is like this:

```
int square(int k)
{
}
```

it satisfies the call because it is a function which accepts one integer as argument and returns `int`.

Then inside the `sum` method, it calls the function which you passed in as the first argument like this (please read my comments inline for clarity):

```
int sum(int(*ptr)(int k),int n)
{
     int s=0;
     for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
         // Calls the function pointer (square in this case) and sends i to
         // it as argument. It then takes the return value and adds it to s.
         s+=(*ptr)(i); 
     }
     return s;
}
```

Here are the different parts:

[image]

Here is another example to help you:

```
// fcnPtr is a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns an integer
int (*fcnPtr)();
```

Comment: why is a pointer used in the argument list (int sum(int(*)(int),int))

Comment: @NiRajWagh I dont understand what you mean